# Displaying a disabled reason when selecting a disabled ListBox item

Tags: wpf, listbox, wpf-4.5

I have a `ListBox` that has items that should not be selectable because they are disabled.  I accomplished this by binding the `IsEnabled` property which disabled the item.  However, I need to be able to display a popup that shows the reason why it's disabled when the user clicks on the disabled item.  What is the best practice for accomplishing something like this?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it this way:

create an hidden transparent control above the listBox. make this control visible when listbox gets invisble. register to MouseDown on this control which will show the popup etc...